# How can I find out what my symbolic link is pointing to?

Tags: unix

Making a bash script, and I am trying to figure out a way to find out what my symbolic link points to. Right now, I am doing it with this, but this only works if my symlink is in the current directory. Is there a way to find out what my symlink is pointing to if it is in another directory?

```
 ls  -l "symlink" | cut -d'>' -f2
```

Answer (score 25):

If you have the `readlink(1)` utility (part of GNU coreutils), it does what you want.  Otherwise you are kinda up a creek, I'm not aware of any straightforward & portable equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

On a BSD toolchain, I am doing:

```
stat -f %Y <filename>
```

For example:

```
% ln -sf /bsd ~/blah        
% stat -f %Y ~/blah
/bsd
```

On a GNU toolchain it is not so easy, you can use something like:

```
$ stat -c %N /usr/bin/firefox
`/usr/bin/firefox' -> `../lib/firefox-3.6.12/firefox.sh'
```

Then, use awk/cut and sed to extract and remove junk quotes.

Or a messier solution is to use `ls -al` and either awk/cut to extract the column you need.